# How to make dll with reference to other dll's inside it

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I'm having some troble getting my project to work because of the dlls.

My problem is:
I have a pdf generating dll ([PdfSharp](https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp)-gdi), but that library doesn't let me sign the pdf files digitally, So I went to GitHub and merged the [pull request](https://github.com/empira/PDFsharp/pull/11) that makes signing pdfs possible with the master.
I thought all was good until I found out that the new merged one doesn't allow me to edit the acrofields of the pdfs.
I tried looking at the code and figuring out what was the problem, but it's too dificult and I have only about 2 days to fix this and other things.

I thought that I could make a dll with the merged library that lets me sign the document, and add a method to sign a document inside it, use the master on my project and then, call the other dll to let me sign the pdfs. But the new dll now asks for the merged library reference.

(I don't know if its clear what I want here)

So I want to make a dll that encloses the PdfSharp that lets signing documents inside it, and use it on my project. without it asking me for the PdfSharp reference on my project.

Comment: Hate to break it to you, but you will probably miss the deadline. If time wasn't an issue, I'd recommend switching to a lib that actually meets your requirements, but I don't see how this could be solved via SO _quickly_ enough. As a last stand, you could spend some small amount of time looking for a lib, that does nothing more than signing? Then just use PdfSharp for the PDF stuff and sign it with the other?

Comment: For a quick fix, I would make a intermediate file from output of the PdfSharp.  and then read PDF into second dll to do the signing.

Comment: I Found an easy Solution, it's not ideal by any means, but it does work, I changed the assemblie's name of the PdfSharp signer version dll, and used that on the project for signing then I also have the regular PdfSharp dll that lets me access the acrofields and everything else, this way there aren't any conflits,